# Weird issue where jQuery AJAX success data only parses last JSON node

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

So I have the following jQuery code:

```
function updateOrderSummary(orderID) {
    var returnString = orderID;
    $.ajax({
        url: "library/getOrderSummary.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: ({returnString:returnString}),
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
}
```

When I run this script, the console shows the following JSON:

```
{"orderDetails":{"orderItem":{"itemName":"351","itemQuantity":"2","itemID":"5-5331fbfd5e0e7","costPerPlay":"2"},"orderItem":{"itemName":"Demo","itemQuantity":"1","itemID":"5-54067191b71e8","costPerPlay":"1"},"orderItem":{"itemName":"314","itemQuantity":"1","itemID":"5-5331f5b41f9f4","costPerPlay":"1"}}}
```

Formatted, it looks like this (for your convenience):

```
{
    "orderDetails": {
        "orderItem": {
            "itemName": "351",
            "itemQuantity": "2",
            "itemID": "5-5331fbfd5e0e7",
            "costPerPlay": "2"
        },
        "orderItem": {
            "itemName": "Demo",
            "itemQuantity": "1",
            "itemID": "5-54067191b71e8",
            "costPerPlay": "1"
        },
        "orderItem": {
            "itemName": "314",
            "itemQuantity": "1",
            "itemID": "5-5331f5b41f9f4",
            "costPerPlay": "1"
        }
    }
}
```

The JSON validates when I run it through JSONLint (jsonlint.com), but I can't seem to parse through the data when I add the dataType: "json" into my script. (ie:)

```
function updateOrderSummary(orderID) {
    var returnString = orderID;
    $.ajax({
        url: "library/getOrderSummary.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: ({returnString:returnString}),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
}
```

When I do this, my console only seems to show the last "node" of the JSON string that gets returned. And I can't seem to parse through it the way I normally do.

Ultimately, all I want to be able to do is get the number of "orderItems" that exist in the return string (in this case, 3), and display the "itemName" for each.  So something like this:

```
for (var a = 0; a < numNodes; a++) {
     returnString += data.orderDetails.orderItem[a].itemName;
}
```

Alas, nothing I do seems to let me drill down into the JSON.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your json structure to below format.    instead of object with same key(orderItem), group it as an array.

```
{
        "orderDetails": {
            "orderItem": [{
                "itemName": "351",
                "itemQuantity": "2",
                "itemID": "5-5331fbfd5e0e7",
                "costPerPlay": "2"
            },
            {
                "itemName": "Demo",
                "itemQuantity": "1",
                "itemID": "5-54067191b71e8",
                "costPerPlay": "1"
            },
             {
                "itemName": "314",
                "itemQuantity": "1",
                "itemID": "5-5331f5b41f9f4",
                "costPerPlay": "1"
            }
          ]
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your structure is set up as object with 3 identical keys.

Since object keys can't be identical the whole property gets over written ...leaving only the last one

Structure needs to be changed to array of objects

SOmething like this would be more appropriate

```
"orderDetails": [
         { "itemName": "351","itemQuantity": "2" ....},
         { "itemName": "567","itemQuantity": "34" ....}
]
```